# Android - Loading Additional Player Scores

Tags: android

I'm writing custom leaderboards for my Android application and am using the Google Play services to get the necessary data.  I'm able to successfully retrieve a page of leaderboard scores that is centered on the currently logged-in user by executing the following call.

```
result = Games.Leaderboards.loadPlayerCenteredScores(getGoogleApiClient(), leaderboardId, LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC, 4, false);
```

However, when I attempt to retrieve the next page of scores using the following service call, I'm receiving a **SERVICE_DISABLED** status code when the service returns its result.

```
result = Games.Leaderboards.loadMoreScores(getGoogleApiClient(), leaderboardScoreBuffer, 10, PageDirection.NEXT);
```

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly when trying to retrieve the next page of scores?  I should point out that loading additional scores works perfectly when I initially load the top page of scores for my leaderboard.  I would think that the Google Play services would allow you to load an additional page of scores when player-centered scores are initially loaded as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was recently facing the same issue. What fixed it for me was to always query for the same number of scores both the first time and in the additional loadMoreScores code.

So if you call

```
result = Games.Leaderboards.loadPlayerCenteredScores(getGoogleApiClient(), leaderboardId, LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC, 4, false);
```

with 4 entries.

then your other call would be

```
result = Games.Leaderboards.loadMoreScores(getGoogleApiClient(), leaderboardScoreBuffer, 4, PageDirection.NEXT);
```

also with 4 entries. This fixed it for me - I know it's a pretty awful fix and I have no idea why it wouldn't work in the usual way, but hope it works for you.

Comment: I set the same number of scores to be returned per page for both the loadPlayerCenteredScores and loadMoreScores calls, and this solved the issue.  Thanks!